# Why we use radix-tree(or xarray) for storing page caches?

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, filesystems, inode

I'm now studying linux kernel with understanding linux kernel (3rd) and I am very confused about the reason why using radix tree for storing whole page caches with using radix tree. (I heard that after version 4.20, kernel uses xarray).

So, here is my question :

Once we want some information of that certain I-node, we should look whole page caches which is pointed by "address_space".

The book says they use radix tree for fast searching for page caches but I can't understand this point.

**Searching what page caches? Don't we need all of them?**

Please give me some examples why we use radix tree for fast searching page caches.

And follow up questions :

If certain "I-node" is the host for address_space, and it holds the radix_tree_root and in this radix tree, we have all the page caches holding all the data related to the file(which is pointed by that I-node)?

Answer (score 0):

Radix tree is a compressed trie where a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a data structure which implements an interface of an associative array and allows to store values as key-value. The keys are usually strings, but any data type can be used. A trie is different from an n-tree because of its nodes. Nodes of a trie do not store keys; instead, a node of a trie stores single character labels. The key which is related to a given node is derived by traversing from the root of the tree to this node. For example:

```
    +-----------+
               |           |
               |    " "    |
               |           |
        +------+-----------+------+
        |                         |
        |                         |
   +----v------+            +-----v-----+
   |           |            |           |
   |    g      |            |     c     |
   |           |            |           |
   +-----------+            +-----------+
        |                         |
        |                         |
   +----v------+            +-----v-----+
   |           |            |           |
   |    o      |            |     a     |
   |           |            |           |
   +-----------+            +-----------+
                                  |
                                  |
                            +-----v-----+
                            |           |
                            |     t     |
                            |           |
                            +-----------+
```

So in this example, we can see the trie with keys, go and cat. The compressed trie or radix tree differs from trie in that all intermediates nodes which have only one child are removed.

Radix trees have a few users in the mainline kernel tree. The PowerPC architecture uses a tree to map between real and virtual IRQ numbers. The NFS code attaches a tree to relevant inode structures to keep track of outstanding requests. The most widespread use of radix trees, however, is in the memory management code. The `address_space` structure used to keep track of backing store contains a radix tree which tracks **in-core pages tied to that mapping**. Among other things, this tree allows the memory management code to quickly find pages which are dirty or under writeback.

Here is a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6544812?arnumber=6544812) for you, which has described this design mechanism really clearly.

Comment: Cite your [sources](https://lwn.net/Articles/175432/).